# how can i refactor multiple only if condition

Tags: c#, if-statement, refactoring

Here i want to check all properties of object one by one and check if it's not `NAN` than apply some logic else skip for each properties.

for that i have to make multiple ifs. is there better way i should do it?

```cs
internal class cls_pro
{
    public double A;
    public double B;
    public double C;
    public double D;
    public double E;
    public double F;
}
```

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        cls_pro obj = new cls_pro();
        obj.A = 1;
        obj.B = 3;
        obj.C = 1;
        obj.D = 23;
        obj.E = double.NaN;
        obj.F = double.NaN;


        // If propertie is not null some logic will apply
        if (!double.IsNaN(obj.A)) { ;}
        if (!double.IsNaN(obj.B)) { ;}
        if (!double.IsNaN(obj.C)) { ;}
        if (!double.IsNaN(obj.D)) { ;}
        if (!double.IsNaN(obj.E)) { ;}
        if (!double.IsNaN(obj.F)) { ;}

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are the "logics" the same logic? Have you heard of an "array"?

Comment: no logic is different for each

Comment: I doubt if `if (!double.IsNaN(obj.D)) {/* some logic here*/}` and alike belongs to `Main` method; I suggest moving it to `cls_pro` class: `internal class cls_pro { public void PerformSomeDLogic(...);...}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, *field*s like `A`, ..., `F` is a **private affair** of `cls_pro` class; that's why I suggest *moving* all

```
 if (!double.IsNaN(obj.A)) { ;}
```

and alike calls into `cls_pro` (let's *rename* it into `ClsPro`):

```
internal class ClsPro {
    //DONE: do not expose fields, but properties
    public double A { get; }
    public double B { get; }
    public double C { get; }
    public double D { get; }
    public double E { get; }
    public double F { get; }

    public ClsPro(double a = double.NaN, 
                  double b = double.NaN, 
                  double c = double.NaN, 
                  double d = double.NaN, 
                  double e = double.NaN, 
                  double f = double.NaN) {
      A = a;
      B = b;  
      C = c;
      D = d;
      E = e; 
      F = f; 
    } 

    public void PerformA() {
      if (double.IsNaN(A)) return;
      /* Some logic here*/
    }

    ...

    public void Perform() {
      PerformA();
      ...
      PerformF();
    }
}
```

Time to execute:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ClsPro obj = new ClsPro(
          a :  1,
          b :  3,
          c :  1,
          d : 23 
        ); 

        obj.Perform();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No better way you **should** to use.

Every condition-based logic of your application can be constructed with 3 different approaches:

#### If-else branching

```cs
if (appliable) { /* do something */ }
else { /* do something different */ }
```

If-else best for short logic branching. If you have not so much conditions this is a good instrument.

#### Switch branching

```cs
switch (logLevel)
{
    case LogLevel.Fatal:
        errorLogger.Fatal(exception);
        break;
    case LogLevel.Error:
        errorLogger.Error(exception, message);
        break;
    case LogLevel.Warning:
        logger.Warn(message);
        break;
    case LogLevel.Info:
        logger.Info(message);
        break;
    case LogLevel.Debug:
        logger.Debug(message);
        break;
    case LogLevel.Trace:
        logger.Trace(message);
        break;
    default:
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(level), level, null);
}
```

Usually, `switch` used for medium logic branching or pattern matching (C# 8.0 gets more good syntax for that). If I have medium size of logic branching - I prefer use it.

#### Strategy pattern

If you have a large logic branching - you must to use strategy pattern.
This pattern is quite simple:

```cs
public class StrategyUser
{
    private IStrategy strategy;

    public StrategyUser(IStrategy strategyToUse)
    {
        this.strategy = strategyToUse;
    }

    public void SetNewStrategy(IStrategy newStrategy)
    {
        this.strategy = newStrategy;
    }
}
```

Strategy can be used for rid of **if-else hell**. Also you can change stretegy directly in runtime to change object behaviour.

I think for your task best approach is to use `if` branching. It's more appropriate.

Comment: right now i am going with @Dmitry ans. i think i can't use `switch` here. but will look into Strategy pattern thank you for suggestion.